# batch insert /update at the same time

Tags: sql

1. Suppose in database i have some 1000 record of  user , hisfriend, timeStampOfChat  (i.e this are column)
2. Now for user (suppose subrata) , we have 30 friends name and its timestamp value. [so there are still 970 records of other user and their friends.]
3. Now i want to update a new data set where user subrata has 50 records out of which few are new and few are old. (for new it should insert the whole  and for old it should update the time stamp.)
4. i want to use batch update/insert.

### Now thats how i want to write the logic

```
if data base has user subrata then batch update time stamp where user = subrata
```

with this i will update the existing records but how to insert the new records out of that 50 record.

Comment: What is this about? What language are you programming or intending to program this in? Please clarify that by adding the appropriate tag or tags. After that, please update your question with: sample data (if applicable), expected results (if applicable), what code you've got at the moment, what you have tried to solve the problem, what particularly you've got difficulties with in your attempts.

Comment: Please note that Batch tag is "used for Windows batch file questions". Don't use it just because your question have "batch" word in any part of it...

Comment: It sounds like you want to look at REPLACE INTO syntax in MySQL.

Comment: Look at the MERGE statement if it is supported by your DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't tagged this question with a RDBMS, but the correct way to do this in MySQL is an [`INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) query.

As long as you define an appropriate index, when the table already contains the row you're trying to insert, it will update the time instead of inserting a copy.

```
INSERT INTO table (user, hisfriend, timeStampOfChat) VALUES (1, 2, 3) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE timeStampOfChat = VALUES(timeStampOfChat)
```